# Insert query is echoing successfully registered but no row insertion happening in phpmyadmin , am using php7 , mysqli and Xampp control panel

Tags: php, mysqli

please, help I am really filled with dread over one week on this , infact I tried all the PHP.ini and my.cfn configuration files, but no thing work . I thought I was the PC thing and jumped to another PC after export n import same database again no effect of insert query in database. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Then you must have inserted it into another database and not into the one which you see in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: My code is here: $insertVoter= "insert into voter('vid','full name','address','birthdate','state','nationality_id') values(null,'$fullname','$address','$birthdate','$state','$nationality_id')";

Comment: I also heard of auto_increment skipping after deleting a row, but I checked that using : ALTER TABLE VOTER AUTO_INCREMENT= 1;